# How to write the result of the query in the state of React?

Tags: reactjs

Good evening.
Half a day to write down the result of the query in the state React.
All code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import axios from "axios";

export default class AllCalcs extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            calcs: []
        };

        this.listItems = '';

        this.fetchData();
        this.getCalcs();
    }

    fetchData() {
        axios.post('/api/all-calcs')
            .then(response => this.setState({calcs: response.data}))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

    getCalcs() {
        this.listItems = this.state.calcs.map((calc, index) =>
            <a key={index} href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
                <div className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                    <h5 className="mb-1">{calc.h1}</h5>
                    <small>3 days ago</small>
                </div>
                <p className="mb-1">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam eget
                    risus varius blandit.</p>
                <small>Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
            </a>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="list-group">
                    {this.listItems}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

if (document.querySelector('#all-calcs')) {
    ReactDOM.render(<AllCalcs />, document.querySelector('#all-calcs'));
}
```

I'm sure an experienced developer will understand what the problem is and tell you in a second. The point is that by / api / all-calcs we get an array with posts. They need to be written in this.state.calcs so that it can be used in the getCalcs method.
Please help me find out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The request is async, so you are setting up the list items before the data comes in. instead you should do it like this.

```
export default class AllCalcs extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { calcs: [] };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() {
    axios
      .post('/api/all-calcs')
      .then(response => this.setState({ calcs: response.data }))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  getCalcs(calcs || []) {
    return calcs.map((calc, index) => (
      <a
        key={index}
        href="#"
        className="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start"
      >
        <div className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
          <h5 className="mb-1">{calc.h1}</h5>
          <small>3 days ago</small>
        </div>
        <p className="mb-1">
          Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Maecenas sed diam
          eget risus varius blandit.
        </p>
        <small>Donec id elit non mi porta.</small>
      </a>
    ));
  }

  render() {
    const { calcs } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="list-group">{this.getCalcs(calcs)}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Essentially what you want to do is kick off the request on `componentDidMount`. And then build the list of items to render when you render. Dont put it on a variable on the class as it is no longer tied to the lifecycle of the class (you wont see updates / render cycles when you store on a property of the class like that)